# How can I convert sql time to java time for an object?

Tags: java, time, java-time, localtime, incompatibletypeerror

When i run this code it says this:

> Error:(43, 31) java: incompatible types: java.sql.Time cannot be
>   converted to java.time.LocalTime

```
public TrackTime read(int id){

        rs = jdbc.queryForRowSet("SELECT * FROM tracktime where id ='" + id + "'");
        while (rs.next()){
            return new TrackTime (rs.getInt("id"),
                    rs.getDate("date"),
                    rs.getTime("startTime"),
                    rs.getTime("endTime"),
                    rs.getString("licenseType"),
                    rs.getInt("trackNumber"));
        }

        return new TrackTime();
    }
```

what can be the cause of this error?

Comment: the cause should be clear, your constructor of the class `TrackTime` expects a `LocalTime` object. Why not doing `.toLocalTime()` then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constructor for `TrackTime` class must be expecting object of class `LocalTime` where as `rs.getTime("startTime")` returns `java.sql.Time` instead of `LocalTime` and as both are not same hence you get the error.

You can use `toLocalTime()` method on `Time` object which returns `LocalTime` object and this way correct object type would get passed to your constructor and should get away from the error.

So in your code you need to do this,

```
while (rs.next()){
    return new TrackTime (rs.getInt("id"),
            rs.getDate("date"),
            rs.getTime("startTime").toLocalTime(),
            rs.getTime("endTime").toLocalTime(),
            rs.getString("licenseType"),
            rs.getInt("trackNumber"));
}
```

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

As others have said already, this must be because you `TrackTime` constructor expects arguments of type `LocalTime` while `rs.getTime` returns `java.sql.Time`.

Assuming JDBC 4.2 (or higher; you probably have that), use `getObject` to retrieve java.time classes like `LocalTime` and also `LocalDate` from your result set:

```
    return new TrackTime (rs.getInt("id"),
            rs.getObject("date", LocalDate.class),
            rs.getObject("startTime", LocalTime.class),
            rs.getObject("endTime", LocalTime.class),
            rs.getString("licenseType"),
            rs.getInt("trackNumber"));
```

I have taken the freedom of also changing the retrieval of the date, which will probably give you a new compile-time error. But now that you are already using java.time, it may be better to change the `TrackTime` constructor to accept a `LocalDate`?

If your JDBC driver is not yet JDBC 4.2 compliant, consider upgrading.